# Bizarre bevel behavior on rounding corners

Tags: edges, bevel

I am attempting to bevel an edge on a part.

The part is comprised of quads with a curved edge at the top. When beveled, I am left with messy overlap on tight corners as shown in the image below. I am beveling in the Width mode, with clamping turned on.
[image: Edge selected to be beveled.]
[image: Beveled edge with overlap circled. Clamping is turned on.]

 In order to get the expected behavior, I had to place edge loops as a sort of "scaffold" to guide the bevel, resulting in what I would have originally expected from the bevel. The beveled vertices do not move in the X axis.
[image: Corrected part with edge to bevel selected.]
[image: Expected bevel behavior - the beveled vertices do not move in the X axis so the part retains it's overall shape and there is no messy overlap.]

 Is there a way to reliably get this sort of behavior without setting up guiding geometry before the bevel? It's tedious and shouldn't be required - I've noticed this limitation time and again and it seems to be a place where blender lacks in part design in comparison to other programs i've used like autodesk Inventor.

Comment: hello, could you please share your object (before the bevel)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots [Here you go.](https://pasteall.org/blend/c7c7cbe25bee4b90be2b852f47f25529)
While creating this scene i found that applying the scale fixed the issue. Does the bevel tool not account for scaled objects?

Comment: oh ok then, scale was the problem here, that said you may have some overlapping faces when you bevel, it may be fixable with the options in the Operator box, if it's not the case there is no magic solution, you need to correct the topology afterwards